# Unable to launch a new activity as main activity

Tags: android, android-activity, startup

Initially my Android project had only one activity named `MainActivity`. Then, I added a new activity named `ChildActivity` into my project. I'm trying to launch my new activity as startup activity when app gets launched. I changed `AndroidManifest.xml` file to achieve it. I moved the  entire `intent-filter` tag from `MainActivity` to `ChildActivity` as shown below:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ChildActivity" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Layout file of `ChildActivity` looks like this. I'm trying to show a `TextView` on the new activity I've just added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChildActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_display"
        android:text="Hello this is Rasik!"/>

</android.support.constraint.FrameLayout>
```

ChildActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.android.explicitintent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ChildActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mDisplayText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child);
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to debug my app in Android AVD, nothing happens. It seems my app is crashing at start up. Can anyone help me in diagnosing the root cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `android.support.constraint.FrameLayout` not exists. Try `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`, `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayour` or others

Comment: I'm just wondering one thing - Whenever I add a new activity using add new activity wizard, then why it is adding `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` control by default into the corresponding layout file on its own? I was adding an empty activity. Android studio is choosing a wrong control which doesn't exist at all. Is there any issue with my project settings which is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

please try this !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_display"
        android:text="Hello this is Rasik!"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

i think there is issue with root framelayout

Comment: I'm just wondering one thing - Whenever I add a new activity using add new activity wizard, then why it is adding `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` control by default into the corresponding layout file on its own? I was adding an empty activity. Android studio is choosing a wrong control which doesn't exist at all. Is there any issue with my project settings which is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You used wrong layout.
Just convert **android.support.constraint.FrameLayout** to **FrameLayout**.
Or convert to default **android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout**

```js
<FrameLayout
    ...>

    <TextView
    ...
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I'm just wondering one thing - Whenever I add a new activity using add new activity wizard, then why it is adding `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` control by default into the corresponding layout file on its own? I was adding an empty activity. Android studio is choosing a wrong control which doesn't exist at all. Is there any issue with my project settings which is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The Root layout `android.support.constraint.FrameLayout` you are using does not exist. Check out this link [Android Developer guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/package-summary).

Your Root layout can be:

- [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout)
- [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout)
- [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout)
- [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)

There are many layouts available which you can use based on your need.

Comment: I'm just wondering one thing - Whenever I add a new activity using add new activity wizard, then why it is adding `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` control by default into the corresponding layout file on its own? I was adding an empty activity. Android studio is choosing a wrong control which doesn't exist at all. Is there any issue with my project settings which is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I had seen a similar issue in another post. Just off the bat, it seems like your child activity is not within the enclosing terms of the ".MainActivity."

Put the child activity into the brackets of the ".MainActivity", in between the 
`<activity android:name=".MainActivity"> </actvitiy>`.  Hopefully that makes it run better. If that doesn't work, start the child activity during the onCreate() method of the MainActivity.

Comment: That is making the `anroidmanifeset.xml` file invalid because of nesting of activity tags. I don't want to use `MainActivity` at all. I want to ignore `MainActivity` altogether.

Comment: That's fair, I was just sure I saw it done somewhere else. You can try manually launching the activity from the MainActivity onCreate, then once its done, it should go back to the MainActivity.